# Writing nested non-blocking loops in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to properly write the following set of loops in Node.Js without blocking the event loop or without causing out of memory error.

What I have tried so far includes

- Combinations of setImmediate()/setInterval()
- The Async module [see my code here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c1a480095e20e253ce1df3084cdb11f)
- Thread_a_gogo (this module is no more maintained)

The code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    for(var j = 0; i < 2000; j++)
        for(var k = 0; k < 2000; k++)
            console.log(i + ":" + j + ":" + k);
```

Also created a JSFiddle to play around [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zbzyqjdp/)

Comment: I don't think the event loop is what you want to use for computations. Its purpose is for handling async IO. Spinning up a new process that does for loops would be better.

Comment: You mean to suggest using child_process for example?

Comment: Your `async.js` code should work, you just have to actually use the asynchronous `setImmediate(cb)` (etc) instead of immediately calling `cb()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what your use-case is. Javascript is blocking as it's single threaded, it would have to run the loop before moving to something else.

You could for example use a generator to run each iteration on an event though.

```
function* ticker() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(let j = 0; i < 10; j++)
        for(let k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            yield[i, j, k];
}

const gen = ticker();

setInterval(() => console.log(gen.next().value), 500);

console.log('I am at the end (called straight away)');
```

Comment: This never stops. You need to test for `.next().done` and when it's `true`, clear the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine `setImmediate`/`setTimeout`/etc. with the async.js library. `async.each` is only for orchestration, it doesn't provide any asynchrony itself.

```
function getPerm(reducedWordList, callback) {
    var sevenLtrWords = _.filter(reducedWordList, word => word.length == 7); 
    var fourLtrWords = _.filter(reducedWordList, word => word.length == 4); 

    async.each(sevenLtrWords, (i, cb) => {
        async.each(sevenLtrWords, (j, cb) => {
            async.each(fourLtrWords, (k, cb) => {
                console.log(i + " " + j + " " + k); 
                setTimeout(cb, 0);
            }, cb);
        }, cb);
    }, callback);
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `setTimeOut()` in the above code, will only let the innermost async to tick the event loop right?

Comment: It's `setTimeout` itself that ticks the event loop. All of these `cb`s just advance their respective iteration when called, and when the array end is met then it calls the next outer callback instead.